# How do I fix link.exe failed: exit code: 3221225595 when compiling a Rust program?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Rust 1.19 and Visual Studio 2017 Community, but rustc prints this message when I try to compile a file with it:

```
linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 3221225595
```

Comment: Generally, Windows error codes are referred to by their hex representation. Chances are good that you have installed a 64-bit version of the software when you have a 32-bit OS or vice-versa.

Comment: If none of the numerous existing Stack Overflow questions about the error solve your problem, please update your question showing all of them that you tried and what you did and we can reopen.